# syntax error before "char" in C

Tags: c, debugging, syntax-error

I have the following piece of code, which when I compile it, I get:

> smash.c:22 error: syntax error before "char"

I don't understand where the problem is. (line 22 is marked by `/*22*/` in the error message, but line numbers do not appear in the code). How can I correct this error?

```
/*some comments...*/
/*some more comments...*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "dir_handling.h"
#include "var_handling.h"



#define     MAXLENGTH           80        

void error_print (char* str)
{
    /*22*/ char *error_message=(*char)malloc((strlen(str)+strlen("smash error: > \"\"\n")+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy (error_message,"smash error: > \"");
    strcat(error_message,str);
    strcat(error_message,"\"\n");
    perror (error_message);
    free (error_message);
    // printf ("smash error: > \"%s\"\n",str);
}
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `(char*)`, as in:

```
char *error_message=(char*)malloc( etc...
```

But note: it is good practice not to cast the return of malloc...

Comment: If I don't cast the return of `malloc` wouldn't it make problems later?

Comment: @Ilya Melamed: no, it would not.

Comment: @Ilya Melamed: Quite the opposite, *casting* the result of `malloc` can potentially lead to problems later.

Comment: Assuming that I don't forget to include `<stdlib.h>` are there any other problems, because it does makes the code more readable (in my opinon)?

Answer (score 3):

`(*char)` should be `(char *)`.